# Example of directshow transform filter for wince

Tags: filter, windows-ce, directshow

I wrote a DirectShow filter for win7 and I have problems to port it to wince6.

Are there any examples for transform filter to wince? I didn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

You will find a few Windows Mobile Directshow fitlers with source here: [GDCL - Tools and Samples for Download](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/downloads.htm).